# Why doesn't rmagick work with devkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm having some difficulty installing rmagick when imagemagick and devkit don't work on windows 10. It keeps stating that devkit could not make a native gem extension. There aren't many resources on the internet that discuss this problem with windows 10, so I have the same issue repeatedly. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: What error do you receive? We are not fortunetellers, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

We have `ImageMagick` & `rmagick` working on Windows 10.

[image]

[image]

Installation is a little tricky. I'll detail how we did it - I'll gladly jump into chat if you need help with it:

---

1. **[Download](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) & Install ImageMagick**

Firstly download the ImageMagick version for your variant of Windows. We're running x64, it should work in x32. The big thing is getting the right version (some don't work).

As can be seen, we're running `ImageMagick 6.9.2` - we'd recommend getting this or the newer version of [`6.9.3`](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.9.3-2-Q16-HDRI-x86-dll.exe):

[image]

**IMPORTANT!!** You need to download the `dll` version (not `static`) (this includes the `C Headers`). The C Headers are used by `rmagick` to build the gem's extensions. If you don't have them, the gem won't install.

**ALSO!!** Install ImageMagick into a path **without spaces**.

---

2. **Install `rmagick`**

You need to reference the installed `ImageMagick` files:

```
gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-dir="C:/path/to/image/magick"
```

**Notice the forward-slashes**

The trick we had to use was using *forward slashes* with our path. If we didn't do that, it wouldn't work.